# MySql subquery as a column and as an alias

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias, where-clause

Since i can't use expression result in the `WHERE` clause, i need to repeat the expression. but since i also use it above, as a column - it seems like a waste of resources.

Can it be avoided?

some code:

```
SELECT field1,
       (SELECT some_field
        FROM   another_table) AS field2
FROM   table_1
WHERE  NOT field2 IS NULL  
# won't work

SELECT field1,
       (SELECT some_field
        FROM   another_table) AS field2
FROM   table_1
WHERE  NOT (SELECT some_field FROM   another_table) IS NULL  
# will work
```

Comment: You can't use alias in `WHERE` of the same level, `WHERE` is evaluating before `SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the predicate from the `WHERE` clause to a `HAVING` clause, and you can reference field2 by it's alias:

In that first query, just change `WHERE` to `HAVING`. That will work.

(The `HAVING` clause operates on the resultset after it's prepared; the `WHERE` clause is evaluated much earlier in the processing, that determines which rows get included in the resultset, and can filter out a lot of rows, which makes things more efficient.

---

NOTE: your query may not be the most efficient approach to getting the resultset you want; but there's not enough information to make a recommendation.